# DataType and DisplayFormatting do not show values in Input Tag in ASP.Net Core 6

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

**What should happen is straightforward: showing a default DateTime in an Input-tag, but without the milliseconds.**

The output (shown below) does not provide the results I would like when using an `<ìnput>` as shown below.
When I use `type="datetime-local"` the formatting is right, but it is shown as text, so no browser-support for date-picking etc.
When I use no 'type=""` The formatting appears fine, but no actual datetime is shown. Any thoughts? I work under the assumption, that I should not separate date and time, and I should not convert it to text, so mobile devices and browsers are able to recognize it as datetime.

[image: Screendump of different HTML-attempts]

I have created a model with a Datefield called Startdatum

```
public class Planner
{
    ....             //removed for simplicity

    [Display(Name = "Startdatum")]
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime), DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime StartPlanDatum { get; set; }
}
```

Part of the PlannerController:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Create()
    {            
        var model = new Planner
        {
            CandidateId = candidateId,
            ProjectId = projectId,
            CustomerId = customerId,
            StartPlanDatum = DateTime.Now
        };
        return View(model);
    }
```

And (part of) the View-Page (Create.cshtml)

```
@model BeaglenoseV4.Models.Planner

        <form id="editForm" asp-action="Create" asp-route-returnUrl="@ViewBag.Back">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="card-body"> 
                <div>
                    <div>
                        <div>HtmlDisplayFor:  @Html.DisplayFor(model => Model.StartPlanDatum)</div>                            
                        <div>Input-tag with type="datetime-local": <input asp-for="StartPlanDatum" type="datetime" /></div>
                        <div>Input-tag with no type: <input asp-for="StartPlanDatum" /></div>
                        <label asp-for="StartPlanDatum">datum</label>
                        <span asp-validation-for="StartPlanDatum" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>                        
                </div>
           </div>
     </form>
```

Comment: `input` is an HTML tag, not an ASP.NET Core tag. How it appears depends on the browser. If the browser doesn't support `type="datetime-local"` the field will behave as `type="text"`. The only browser that doesn't support it is IE11 though. Have you checked [the MDN page for `datetime-local](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/datetime-local) ?

Answer (score 0):

try using:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.StartPlanDatum, "datepicker")
```